# ServletContextAware bean getting initialized too early when using @SpringBootTest with @AutoConfigureMockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I'm seeing an odd issue when using `@SpringBootTest` with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. I have a SpringBoot project setup with an **application.yaml** file that provides a custom `server.servlet.context-path`, this value is used in a platform layer, using a `ServletContextAware` bean, to get context information for creating an Open API specification. When the application is launched normally, everything works as expected. The `ServletContext` is updated with context path in `ServerProperties.setContextPath()`, then `setServletContext()` is called on my bean. When it is run via a JUnit, this happens in reverse order. I first see `setServletContext()` called on my bean before the **application.yaml** data is loaded and I do not get the updated context path.

**Spring Boot App**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yaml**

```yaml
server.servlet.context-path: /some/custom/path
```

**Servlet context aware configuration bean**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration implements ServletContextAware {

    ...

    public void setServletContext(@NonNull ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

**JUnit**

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application .class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @theprogrammer No, it doesn't look like I did. I probably just gave up and kept it with an empty base path since that is what I am still seeing in our docs folder.